# Deleting value in a hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a hashmap that is populated already. I have abc123 mapped to 123.

I first declare an object called test and give it a value of abc123

I then check if my hashmap contains abc123.

If it is true it will go into the if statement and get the mapping of the abc123 and put it into a string called value

I then want to replace abc123 with just 123

Now my hashmap key is 123 and my value is 123

How would I get rid of the value of 123

I want to be able to print out the mapping to 123 and get null

```
public void replace1(Map<String, String> barcodeMap) {
  Object test = "abc123";

  if (barcodeMap.containsKey(test)) {

     System.out.println("HERE I WILL PRINT THE MAPPING OF AGILENT         " + barcodeMap.get(test)); //output here is 123

     String value = barcodeMap.get(test);

     System.out.println("THE MAPPING OF VALUE SHOULD BE NULL     " + barcodeMap.get(value)); //output here is null

     barcodeMap.put(value, barcodeMap.remove(test));

     System.out.println("HERE I WILL PRINT THE MAPPING OF AGILENT it should be null:::::   " + barcodeMap.get(test)); //output here is null

     System.out.println("HERE IS THE MAPPING OF VALUE::::::::::::::       " + barcodeMap.get(value)); //output here is 123, i want it to be null here

  }
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`remove` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29) to remove key/value pairs from a `Map` (see the linked docs).

```
barcodeMap.remove(value);
```

...I'm still not clear on why you're doing whatever you're doing though, since you're adding a key/value pair that you apparently don't want in the `Map`.

---

If you want the **key to remain** but have `null` as its value, that's even simpler--just add the key with the value you actually want. All in one line now:

```
barcodeMap.put(barcodeMap.remove(test), null);
```

This adds the result of `barcodeMap.remove(test)` as a key to `barcodeMap`, with a value of `null`.

Comment: When I do use barcodeMap.remove(value); it deletes that entry completley from my hashmap, I still want the key to be there, just not its mapping, for example if after I use barcodeMap.remove(value); and do the following

 if (barcodeMap.containsKey(value)) {
            System.out.println("SUCCCCCEEEEEEESSSSSS");
         }

I would want to get to success but the value is deleted completley

Comment: @user2811419 Ah, I see. I've updated my answer to address that.

Answer (score 2):

Instead `barcodeMap.put(value, barcodeMap.removre(test));` use

`barcodeMap.remove(test);
 barcodeMap.put(value, null);`

Answer (score 1):

Check the JavaDoc for HashMap.

There is a remove() method.

Comment: When I do use barcodeMap.remove(value); it deletes that entry completley from my hashmap, I still want the key to be there, just not its mapping, for example if after I use barcodeMap.remove(value); and do the following

 if (barcodeMap.containsKey(value)) {
            System.out.println("SUCCCCCEEEEEEESSSSSS");
         }

I would want to get to success but the value is deleted completley

Comment: You can just add a null value for the same key and it should overwrite the previous value.